# Which of these workout routines would result in more workouts per year?

Tags: combinations

Person A exercises 3 times a week: Mon, Wed, Fri - for the whole year. That's 3 days a week X 52 weeks = 156 total sessions.

Person B exercises every other day: e.g. Mon, Wed, Fri, Sun, Tue, Thu, Sat, Mon...

So how many total sessions does Person B do in the same year?

I know there might be variables such as what day the year starts, leap year etc, I just want to know generally which person does more sessions in total in a year.

Thanks.

Comment: One person works out $3$ days per week, the other $3.5$ days per week.

Comment: If you assume person B exercises on New Year's Day, then he/she will exercise at least 182 days a year (since there are 365 days in a non-leap year).

Comment: Thanks to you both. With your help I have figured out the calculation too! 52 weeks/2 = 26 X 7 days = 182.

Answer (score 1):

Leap years do not affect the sequence of days in the week, or the alteration of one day after the other.  So the 3-a-week guy does, well, 3 in a week, and the alternator does 3.5 a week, on average.  So the alternator does $\frac{1}{6}$  more...